# Flexdashboard storyboard data-commentary formatting (headers)

Tags: r, comments, flexdashboard

I was wondering if It is possible in a "flexdashboard dashboard storyboard" (https://rstudio.github.io/flexdashboard/articles/using.html#storyboards-1) to change the format of the data comments section. White box at the right of the chart. Specifically I want to add headers , but when I add "##", the "comment" section ends up as text at the top of the storyboard, instead of its position at the right side (see image)
[image]

Here the my code:

````html
---
title: "Storyboard Commentary"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    storyboard: true
---

### Frame 1

```{r}
```

*** 

### Some commentary about Frame 1.

* This is a comment in a unordered list
* This is my final **comment**
* look at the url of this comment[myurl]

### Frame 2 {data-commentary-width=400}

```{r}
```

*** 

Some commentary about Frame 2.
````

Answer (score 0):

I realized the answer thanks to this nice explained post at
[github](https://github.com/rstudio/flexdashboard/issues/265).

Basically :

*With flexdashboard, title levels have different meaning, and the first 3 each serves a purpose.
Level 1 are for pages (see about multiple pages
Level 2 are for definining the layout, Row or Column. See about orientation
Level 3 are for defining the component, and define the title of each boxes. See about title. They are also uses to defines tabset name (See about tab row)*

Problem solved, then! Now I have to figure out how to solve how to add multiple plots in a dashboard and keep the right panel (comments) at the left. It seems that [this answer](https://community.rstudio.com/t/multiple-plots-on-a-storyboard-page/33986/2)  enables to add multiple plots in a storyboard. But in my screen the comments sections moves to the bottom of the box, instead of keep itself at the right side. I will post another issue in another post in Stackoverflow.